# AWS EC2 User data ,multiple PowerShell commands don't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, user-data

when I use this PowerShell commands together in EC2 user data:

```
<powershell>
                        
Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core -source \\network\share\sxs;
                                
curl.exe --output v.exe --url https://cdn.vmix.com/download/vmix24.exe;
                                
Start-Process C:\\Users\\Administrator\\v.exe -ArgumentList "/VERYSILENT" -Wait -NoNewWindow 
</powershell>
<persist>true</persist>
```

When start the instance, The first command just run, and other commands don't work.
how can I execute them all.

Comment: Nothing runs after `Install-WindowsFeature`?

Comment: Temporarily remove that line - does everything else run normally?

Comment: yes, Nothing runs after Install-WindowsFeature

Comment: I can't download the VMIX without .NET framework 3.5

Comment: Run that exact command manually in the EC2 instance and see if it fails

Comment: It worked when I Run that commands manually in powershell

Comment: Are you actually trying to run `curl.exe`, or are you hoping to rely on the `curl` alias offered by PowerShell to call `Invoke-WebRequest`?  Maybe try dropping the `.exe`

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary  please I need the command you deleted